Why does my Apple TV open the Control Center immediately when I turn it on?
This started happening a while ago and I don't remember whether I changed any settings that could have caused this.
Basically, after turning it off for the day, the next day, I press the Power button on the AppleTV controller, and it turns on, and the Control Center is opened. It didn't used to be like that, did it?
How can I fix this?

What version of tvOS are you running?

the tvOS version is 17.5.1

If you are using an LG TV then disable "Auto Power Sync" on the TV, that should fix the issue.

Hey, welcome. Please avoid posting answers that aren't actual answers. I understand it might be frustrating, please take time to read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead.

@Thinkr I came back to add the answer just in case the OP is using an LG tv.
